# Unable to parse template "Class" - Is there a way to configure HibernateUtil class in Intellj Idea?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I use Hibernate for the object relational mapping in my project (maven). I use Intellij, version 2020.1.

When I try to create my HibernateUtil(HibernateUtil.java) class I get the following error:

*Unable to parse template "Class"
Error message: Selected class file name 'HibernateUtil.java' mapped to not java file type 'Files supported via TextMate bundles'*

Does anyone know the problem?

How can I get around this error message? Do I need to change something in intellj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the problem by adding a wildcard to the registered patterns for java.

[image]
*Settings-> editor -> File Types*